# Como alterar cabeçalho http usando ().get e ().post()?

Tags: jquery, http-headers, jwt

De forma bem resumida eu preciso enviar no cabeçalho http das requisições um token jwt, como eu posso alterar os cabeçalhos das requisições jQuery `$.post()` e `$.get()`?

Exemplo de como eu faço usando curl pelo prompt:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhcHAudGVjbWFuLmNvbSIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiSmVhbiBGcmVpdGFzIiwiZW1haWwiOiJoZW5yaXF1ZWszQGxpdmUuY29tIiwiYWNsIjpbInJoIiwiZmluYW5jZWlybyIsImNvbWVyY2lhbCIsImVuZ2VuaGFyaWEiLCJhZG1pbmlzdHJhdGl2byJdfQ==.kq4nJJYBTbjWwtbmu\/wB+EXilDHHPr8es6mXpsXEVMs=" http://meuapp.com/jwt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar algo como:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://meuapp.com/jwt",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data, status) {
    return console.log("Dados", data);
  },
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + token); } 
});
```

[Jquery ajax setting](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)